# How should i handle image load in php & apache

Tags: php, image, apache

I build my own picture gallery for my site with jquery and php.

The picture is quite big, about 200 KB. my hosting is bandwidth metered, not unlimited bandwidth.  And than i try to optimize it with php every request that point to those image and surprisingly php handle it well. it can optimize image about 75% become about 50 KB with a almost similar image from the original one.

what do you think is better? i optimize the image every request with php or let apache handle image request but i need manualy optimize the image (with Photoshop) before i upload it to my webserver?

ps : i also need to track every image request, use ajax and build my own tracker for every request for page including ajax request.

Comment: if you are short with budget, you can consider image hosting like amazon s3 (http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#pricing)

Comment: yeah, i fell stupid to host my site in this place. another hosting give the same price with unlimited bandwidth and 1500% more space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would process every image once when it's requested for first time and store processed image to new file. next time when file is requested we should look if there exists its processed copy and let the apache do the rest of job.

Comment: hi heximal, yes i already do what you say. resize the image than place it to another place. but i only get about 50% image. but with combination imagecreatefromjpeg and imagejpeg i get another 25% file size reduction.